# How can I automate a function, and use a string inside list and then repeat it with the next string in the list?

Tags: python, function, automated-tests

I have a list of strings, which I want to use each string at a time in a function.

How can I repeat the function and also in the function move to the next string?

For example:

```
def search():
    search_for_user = browser.find_element_by_xpath("/" + search_path)
    search_for_user.send_keys(users[0])

    sleep(2)

    click_on_user = browser.find_element_by_xpath("/" + user_path)
    click_on_user.click()

def search():
    search_for_user = browser.find_element_by_xpath("/" + search_path)
    search_for_user.send_keys(users[1])

    sleep(2)

    click_on_user = browser.find_element_by_xpath("/" + user_path)
    click_on_user.click()
```

I want to automate this process, can anyone help me out?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use a loop
ex:

```
def search(indix):
    search_for_user = browser.find_element_by_xpath("/" + search_path)
    search_for_user.send_keys(users[indix])

    sleep(2)

    click_on_user = browser.find_element_by_xpath("/" + user_path)
    click_on_user.click()
for i in range(0,100):
    search(i)
```

I hop that can help you!

Answer (score 0):

Just use a loop and pass the list as parameter in the function.

```
def search(users):
    for user in users:
        search_for_user = browser.find_element_by_xpath("/" + search_path)
        search_for_user.send_keys(user)

        sleep(2)

        click_on_user = browser.find_element_by_xpath("/" + user_path)
        click_on_user.click()

search([user1, user2, user3])
```